# Dynamically show url_for image in html file flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to display an image of an item whose name is saved as  **1.jpg** where 1 is item id.
I am trying to show it using url_for but the image is not showing.

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static',filename='img/uploads/item.id.jpg')}}" alt="img">
```

Is there a way i can dynamically insert item.id value in url_for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sample should work:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static',filename='img/uploads/' + item.id + '.jpg')}}" alt="img">
{% endfor %}
```

[ if id is integer then convert to string like `item.id|string` ]

Comment: It gives **str is undefined**. Here jinja2 isnt  able to convert the integer to string